# CNTK Python API: access layers after loading model

Tags: python, cntk

I can not access layers after loading the model.

I created the model as follows:

```
def create_model(vocab_dim, hidden_dim):

    input_seq_axis1 = Axis('inputAxis1')
    input_sequence_before = sequence.input_variable(shape=vocab_dim, sequence_axis=input_seq_axis1, is_sparse = use_sparse)
    input_sequence_after = sequence.input_variable(shape=vocab_dim, sequence_axis=input_seq_axis1, is_sparse = use_sparse)
    e=Sequential([
        C.layers.Embedding(hidden_dim),
        Stabilizer()
        ],name='Embedding')
    a = Sequential([
        e,  
        C.layers.Recurrence(C.layers.LSTM(hidden_dim//2),name='ForwardRecurrence'),
        ],name='ForwardLayer')
    b = Sequential([
        e,  
        C.layers.Recurrence(C.layers.LSTM(hidden_dim//2),go_backwards=True),
       ],name='BackwardLayer')
    latent_vector = C.splice(a(input_sequence_before), b(input_sequence_after))

    bias = C.layers.Parameter(shape = (vocab_dim, 1), init = 0, name='Bias')
    weights = C.layers.Parameter(shape = (vocab_dim, hidden_dim), init = C.initializer.glorot_uniform(), name='Weights')
    z = C.times_transpose(weights, latent_vector,name='Transpose') + bias
    z = C.reshape(z, shape = (vocab_dim))

    return z
```

Then I load the model:

```
def load_my_model(vocab_dim, hidden_dim):

    z=load_model("models/lm_epoch0.dnn")
    input_sequence_before = z.arguments[0]
    input_sequence_after = z.arguments[1]
    a=z.ForwardLayer
    b=z.BackwardLayer
    latent_vector = C.splice(a(input_sequence_before), b(input_sequence_after))
```

I get an error: TypeError("argument ForwardRecurrence's type SequenceOver[inputAxis1][Tensor[100]] is incompatible with the type SequenceOver[inputAxis1][SparseTensor[50000]] of the passed Variable",)

It looks like the layer referenced by name (z.ForwardLayer) represents the function from the layer immediate input. How can I calculate "latent_vector" (I need this variable to create cross entropy and loss functions to continue training) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error, the dimensions of your input seq is too big (5000) compared to what your ForwardLayer expects (100).

When you select the node ForwardLayer via `z.ForwardLayer`, you are only select that very specific node/layer, but not the layers/nodes/rest of the computation graphs that is connected to it.

You should do `a = C.combine([z.ForwardLayer.owner])` and you should be fine.

Comment: yes, dimention of 100 is probably hidden_dim//2 - immediate input to this layer. But I need to calculate latent_vector as a function of input to the model (50000) - like it is done in create_model function.

Comment: Is the input to your original model the same as your current input (5000 dimension)?

Comment: Two inputs to original model (input_sequence_before and input_sequence_after) are of 50000 dimension (vocab_dim). The same inputs to loaded model are of 50000 dimension as well.

Comment: @Andrey i updated my original answer, it should solve your problem now